# JavaScript fractal generation algorithms - why is one so much faster?

Tags: javascript, performance, fractals

I'm trying to write a JavaScript fractal generation algorithm from first principles. I'm aware that there are many examples out there but I wanted to incorporate additional functionality to support both Mandelbrot and 'spinning' Julia with variants such as 'Burning Ship' and 'Tricorn'. With this in mind I implemented a lightweight Complex maths library (*again, I'm aware there are standard Complex js libraries out there but I wanted to build one from scratch as a learning exercise*).

I tested two alternate functions, one `fractal` using standard maths functions and the other `fractalComplex` using my Complex library methods. They both work fine, but I was surprised to find that the standard version is almost **twice as fast** as the Complex version. I was expecting some additional overhead but not that much!

Can anyone explain why? The Complex library is using the same maths constructs 'under the covers'. Is the additional overhead purely down to object creation?

The code is reproduced below (the input parms z and c are objects of the form `{re, im}`).

```
function fractal(z, c, maxiter) {

    var i, za, re, im, re2, im2;
    c = (settype === JULIA ? c : z);

    // Iterate until abs(z) exceeds escape radius
    for (i = 0; i < maxiter; i += 1) {

        if (setvar === BURNING_SHIP) {
            re = Math.abs(z.re);
            im = -Math.abs(z.im);
        }
        else if (setvar === TRICORN) {
            re = z.re
            im = -z.im; // conjugate z
        }
        else { // Mandelbrot
            re = z.re;
            im = z.im;
        }

        re2 = re * re;
        im2 = im * im;
        z = { // z = z² + c
            re: re2 - im2 + c.re,
            im: 2 * im * re + c.im
        };

        za = re2 + im2 // abs(z)²
        if (za > 4) { // abs(z)² > radius²
            break;
        }
    }
    za = Math.sqrt(za); // abs(z)
    return { i, za };
}

function fractalComplex(z, c, maxiter, n, radius) {

    var i, za;
    c = (settype === JULIA ? c : z);

    // Iterate until abs(z) exceeds escape radius
    for (i = 0; i < maxiter; i += 1) {

        if (setvar === BURNING_SHIP) {
            z = new Complex(Math.abs(z.re), -Math.abs(z.im))
        }
        if (setvar === TRICORN) {
            z = z.conjugate()
        }

        z = z.quad(n, c); // z = zⁿ + c
        za = z.abs();
        if (za > radius) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return { i, za };
}
```

My "Complex lite" library is as follows:

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A basic complex number library which implements the methods used for
// Mandelbrot and Julia Set generation.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
'use strict';

// Instantiate complex number object.
function Complex(re, im) {
  this.re = re; // real
  this.im = im; // imaginary
}

Complex.prototype = {

  're': 0,
  'im': 0,

  // Set value.
  'set': function (re, im) {
    this.re = re;
    this.im = im;
  },

  // Get magnitude.
  'abs': function () {
    return Math.sqrt(this.re * this.re + this.im * this.im);
  },

  // Get polar representation (r, θ); angle in radians.
  'polar': function () {
    return { r: this.abs(), θ: Math.atan2(this.im, this.re) };
  },

  // Get square.
  'sqr': function () {
    var re2 = this.re * this.re - this.im * this.im;
    var im2 = 2 * this.im * this.re;
    return new Complex(re2, im2);
  },

  // Get complex number to the real power n.
  'pow': function (n) {
    if (n === 0) { return new Complex(1, 0); }
    if (n === 1) { return this; }
    if (n === 2) { return this.sqr(); }
    var pol = this.polar();
    var rn = Math.pow(pol.r, n);
    var θn = n * pol.θ;
    return cart(rn, θn);
  },

  // Get conjugate.
  'conjugate': function () {
    return new Complex(this.re, -this.im);
  },

  // Get quadratic zⁿ + c.
  'quad': function (n, c) {
    var zn = this.pow(n);
    return new Complex(zn.re + c.re, zn.im + c.im);
  },

  // Rotate by angle in radians.
  'rotate': function (angle) {
    var pol = this.polar();
    angle += pol.θ;
    return new Complex(pol.r * Math.cos(angle), pol.r * Math.sin(angle));
  },

  // String in exponent format to specified significant figures.
  'toString': function (sig = 9) {
    return this.re.toExponential(sig) + " + " + this.im.toExponential(sig) + "i";
  },
}

// Convert polar (r, θ) to cartesian representation (re, im).
function cart(r, θ) {
  var re = r * Math.cos(θ);
  var im = r * Math.sin(θ);
  return new Complex(re, im);
}
```

Additional edit 22/12/2021 11:52:

For what it's worth, this is what I eventually settled on...

```
   function fractal(p, c, n, maxiter, radius) {

        var i, za, zre, zim, tre, cre, cim, r, θ;
        var lastre = 0;
        var lastim = 0;
        var per = 0;
        if (setmode === JULIA) {
            cre = c.re;
            cim = c.im;
            zre = p.re;
            zim = p.im;
        }
        else { // Mandelbrot mode
            cre = p.re;
            cim = p.im;
            zre = 0;
            zim = 0;
        }

        // Iterate until abs(z) exceeds escape radius
        for (i = 0; i < maxiter; i += 1) {

            if (setvar === BURNING_SHIP) {
                zre = Math.abs(zre);
                zim = -Math.abs(zim);
            }
            else if (setvar === TRICORN) {
                zim = -zim; // conjugate z
            }

            // z = z² + c
            if (n == 2) {
                tre = zre * zre - zim * zim + cre;
                zim = 2 * zre * zim + cim;
                zre = tre;
            }
            else { // z = zⁿ + c, where n is integer > 2
                r = powi(Math.sqrt(zre * zre + zim * zim), n); // radiusⁿ
                //r = Math.pow(Math.sqrt(zre * zre + zim * zim), n); // radiusⁿ
                θ = n * Math.atan2(zim, zre); // angleⁿ
                zre = r * Math.cos(θ) + cre;
                zim = r * Math.sin(θ) + cim;
            }

            // Optimisation - periodicity check speeds
            // up processing of points within set
            if (PERIODCHECK) {
                if (zre === lastre && zim === lastim) {
                    i = maxiter;
                    break;
                }
                per += 1;
                if (per > 20) {
                    per = 0;
                    lastre = zre;
                    lastim = zim;
                }
            }
            // ... end of optimisation

            za = zre * zre + zim * zim // abs(z)²
            if (za > radius) { // abs(z)² > radius²
                break;
            }
        }
        return { i, za };
    }

    // Optimised pow() function for integer exponents
    // using 'halving and squaring'.
    function powi(base, n) {

        var res = 1;
        while (n) {
            if (n & 1) { // if n is odd
                res *= base;
            }
            n >>= 1; // n * 2
            base *= base;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: What engine did you use to run the code, and how many iterations did you try?

Comment: @Bergi I've run it natively in a Firefox browser (95.0.1) and also under Node.js 16.13.1 (the intention was to deploy as both a web site or an Electron app). For maxiter I used both a fixed maxiter of 100 and an algorithm which automatically increases the maxiter with zoom level (see following). I'm seeing the same performance differential in all cases:  `function getAutoiter(zoom) {
        return Math.max(MAXITER, parseInt(Math.abs(1000 * Math.log(1 / Math.sqrt(zoom)))));
    }`

Comment: @Bergi To give you some metrics; Based on a 750 x 500 pixel canvas, I'm seeing a total execution time of around 190ms for the `fractal` version and 280ms for the `fractalComplex` version (the rest of the code is identical).

Comment: "The Complex library is using the same maths constructs 'under the covers'. "  Please clarify what is meant by this statement, as `fractal` and `fractalComplex` not only have different parameters, but the additional `radius` parameter in the latter is involved in the logic to break out of the `for` loop...  Plus the `fractal` calculation of `z = z**2 + c` is replaced in `fractalComplex` with a call to `quad`, which then calls `pow` which in turn calls `polar` and `cart`...  Ie, there does not appear to be similar conversions to polar and cartesian coordinates in the `fractal` calculations...

Comment: @Trentium Thanks for the response. Sorry, I should have clarified that for comparative purposes I'm using a bailout radius of 2 and a standard exponent (n) of 2 in both cases, in which case the `fractalComplex` `pow()` function avoids polar conversions and uses the simplied `sqr` calculation which I believe is identical to that used in `fractal`. So AFAICS it's a 'like for like' comparison in terms of the actual mathematical functions, the only difference being that the `fractalComplex` library is instantiating a bunch of `Complex` objects in the process. What am I missing?

Comment: One experiment I would try is to have the Complex methods operate on the object itself rather than return a new object.  Ie, change `conjugate` from `return new Complex(this.re, -this.im);` to `this.im = -this.im; returh this;`, particularly since `fractalComplex` appears to simply set `z` to some method of `z` in all cases.  The same goes for `quad`.  Additionally, the `z = new Complex(Math.abs(z.re), -Math.abs(z.im))` can be changed to `z.re=Math.abs(z.re); z.im=Math.abs(z.im)`, and move the creation of `z` before the `for` loop...

Comment: Another path worth taking is to make use of `performance.now()` at critical code points to determine the source of the additional time in `fractalComplex`.  Eg, wrap the `z = z ** n + c` code in both `fractal` and `fractalComplex` with `startTimer=performance.now()` and `stopTimer=performance.now()-startTimer`, capturing the stats on stopTimer.  This will allow you to narrow the performance issues with empirical data...

Comment: @Trentium. Thanks for that. I think you're basically confirming my suspicion that the additional overhead is due to object instantiation. I did consider amending my `complexlite.py` library along the lines you suggest for my own purposes, but I had a look at the 'official' Infusion `complex.js` library and that functions much as mine does (i.e. most of the operations return a new Complex object), so I can only imagine it must incur the same overhead. For my fractal project I've decided to go with standard maths operators in the interests of speed and exploit some other optimisation tricks.

Comment: In the purely real implementation you could order the calculation so that variables `zre2=zre*zre` and `zim2=zim*zim` can be both used in the new `zre` and in the radius comparison. This would require to do the radius check first, then the new point. As this reduces 6 multiplications to 4 in the dominant calculation block, the computation time should be reduced by some noticeable amount.

Comment: @LutzLehmann That's a worthwhile improvement - thanks! Obviously with a process as massively iterative as this, even the tiniest additional overhead gets magnified. I'm thinking the best compromise solution might be is to use inline standard (real) methods when the exponent is 2  - the most common case - but invoke the `Complex.pow()` function (or an inline equivalent) for all other exponents, and live with the inevitable performance hit.

Comment: `pow`, the real variant, is a rather elaborate procedure in most math libraries. `exp(y*ln(x))` is not accurate enough. Integer powers below 5, perhaps even below 10, are faster using halving-and-squaring.

Comment: @s949 am not fully clear on the overarching algorithm, but all the discussions so far seem to be focused on a single threaded solution.  Bear in mind that WASM can aid in accelerating single threaded Javascript processes (although at the expense of more complex coding), and additionally Web Workers allow for multiple concurrent threads.  Furthermore, there are libraries such as tensorflow.js and gpu.js that allow you to marshall data to and from the GPU to perform floating point operations en masse via matrices...

Comment: I followed your tip of an alternate pow() function for integer exponents using 'halving and squaring' and I'm surprised at how much quicker it is! (why don't the standard maths libraries build in such optimisations?). This is basically a learning exercise for me so I wanted to start by seeing how much I can squeeze out of a single-threaded process using simple constructs. Next step will be to explore the various browser-supported concurrency frameworks available, including WASM, but that's a bit further up my learning curve at the moment. Thanks for the tips, people.

Answer (score 0):

The following class might satisfy both performance concerns and proper encapsulation of the Complex object...

Notables:

- Where applicable, always return the `this` Complex object (ie, the instantiated object), which facilitates chaining.  Eg,

  - x = new Complex( 10, 5 ).sqrThis().powThis( 1 );
- For every Complex method that returns a Complex object, configure two (2) methods:

  - A method, dubbed `<method>This` that operates directly on the `this` object and contains the function logic.
  - A method, dubbed `<method>` that clones a new Complex object from the `this` object, and then calls `<method>This` to execute the function logic on the clone.
  - This provides the developer the choice of methods that either updates the existing object or returns a new object.
- Internal calls to other Complex methods generally should use the `<method>This` version, as the initial call establishes whether to use the existing `this` object in-place, or to clone it.  From there, all internal calls to the other Complex methods will either continue to operate on the `this` object or the clone.

```js
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A basic complex number library which implements the methods used for
// Mandelbrot and Julia Set generation.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
'use strict';

class Complex {

  constructor( reOrComplex, im ) {
    this.set( reOrComplex, im );
  }
  
  set( reOrComplex, im ) {
    if ( reOrComplex instanceof Complex ) {
      this.re = reOrComplex.re;
      this.im = reOrComplex.im;
    } else {
      this.re = reOrComplex;
      this.im = im;
    }
    return this;
  }
  
  abs() {
    return Math.sqrt(this.re * this.re + this.im * this.im);
  }

  toPolar() {
    return { r: this.abs(), θ: Math.atan2(this.im, this.re) };
  }

  sqrThis() {
    return this.set( this.re * this.re - this.im * this.im, 2 * this.im * this.re );
  }
  
  sqr() {
    return new Complex( this ).sqrThis();
  }

  powThis( n ) {
    if ( n === 0 ) { return this.set( 1, 0 ) };
    if ( n === 1 ) { return this; }
    if ( n === 2 ) { return this.sqrThis(); }
    let polar = this.toPolar();
    return this.toCartesianThis( Math.pow(polar.r, n), n * polar.θ );
  }
  
  pow( n ) {
    return new Complex( this ).powThis( n );
  }

  conjugateThis() {
    return this.set( this.re, -this.im);
  }
  
  conjugate() {
    return new Complex( this ).conjugateThis();
  }

  quadraticThis( n, c ) {
    let zn = this.powThis( n );
    return this.set( zn.re + c.re, zn.im + c.im );
  }

  quadratic( n, c ) {
    return new Complex( this ).quadraticThis( n, c );
  }

  rotateThis( deltaAngle ) {
    let polar = this.toPolar();
    let angle = polar.θ + deltaAngle;
    return this.set( polar.r * Math.cos(angle), polar.r * Math.sin(angle) );
  }
  
  rotate( deltaAngle ) {
    return new Complex( this ).rotateThis( deltaAngle );
  }

  toString( sig = 9 ) {
    return this.re.toExponential( sig ) + " + " + this.im.toExponential( sig ) + "i";
  }
  
  toCartesianThis( r, θ ) {
    return this.set( r * Math.cos( θ ), r * Math.sin( θ ) );
  }
}

// Convert polar (r, θ) to cartesian representation (re, im).
Complex.toCartesian = function ( r, θ ) {
  return new Complex().toCartesianThis( r, θ );
}


let x = new Complex( 10, 5 ).sqrThis();
console.log( 'x = new Complex( 10, 5 ).sqrThis()' );
console.log( 'x is ', x );
let y = x.pow( 3 );
console.log ( 'y = x.pow( 3 )' );
console.log ( 'y is ', y );
x.sqr();
console.log ( 'x.sqr()' );
console.log ( 'x is still', x );
x.sqrThis();
console.log ( 'x.sqrThis()' );
console.log ( 'x is now', x );
```

In short, structuring a class this way provides two versions of the same method:

- One method which embodies the function logic and directly mutates the instantiated `this` object.
- And the other method which simply clones the instantiated `this` object, and then calls the associated method containing the function logic.